Getting "Authentication failed" error for API call with USER_KEY on 3Scale
I have successfully created an API service on the OpenShift console, and it is functioning as expected. However, when I integrate it with 3Scale, I encounter a 403 Authentication failed error.
Here is the cURL command I used:
curl "https://otp-sms-preprod-apicast-staging.apps.ocp-isb-prod.test.com:443/one-time-password-sms/v0/validate-code?user_key=USER_KEY"
